# How to change Angular Mat table head row Background color, font etc

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have been attempting to make an Angular Mat table and I have it working, but I cannot figure out how to customize the header row. I need to change the background color and text color. I cannot figure out how to do it.
Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your css file,

```
th.mat-header-cell {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Me ayudo mucho la respuesta. gracias